# Equilibrium constant when given Ka and Kb of reactants

Tags: equilibrium

[image]
The first problem has completely stumped me on even how to begin. I just need some sort of direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should help to look at the form of the constants:

$K_\mathrm{eq}=\ce{\frac{[NH4^+][CN^-]}{[HCN][NH3]}}$

For $\ce{HCN}$, $K_\mathrm{a}=\ce{\frac{[H^+][CN^-]}{[HCN]}}$

For $\ce{NH3}$, $K_\mathrm{b}=\ce{\frac{[OH^-][NH4^+]}{[NH3]}} = \frac{K_\mathrm{w} \cdot \ce{[NH4^+]}}{\ce{[NH3][H^+]}}$ where $K_\mathrm{w}=\ce{[H^+][OH^-]} = {1*10^{-14}}$

Is there anyway you can use some combination of $K_\mathrm{a}$ and $K_\mathrm{b}$ to get $K_\mathrm{eq}$?

Comment: So could I treat it like a Hess's law in a way where I add the Ka and the Kb and the reverse of Kw to get the overall equation then multiply them all?

Comment: You can treat it similar to Hess's law. However, I would just look at the product of $K_a$ and $K_b$. How does this product compare to $K_{eq}$?

Comment: Thanks for the help I ended up getting it how you could figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

$K_\mathrm{eq}=\ce{\frac{[CN^-] [H+][NH4^+] [OH-]}{[HCN][NH3] [OH-][H+]}}$

$K_\mathrm{eq}=\ce{\frac{$K_\mathrm{a}$K_\mathrm{b}}{K_\mathrm{w}}}$

$K_\mathrm{eq}=\ce{\frac{(4.0*10^10-)(1.8*10^5-) }{10^14- }}$ = 0.72